# objective-c : unable to understand the exception producer place from stack trace?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, exception

I am new to iphone developement, during development I face problem due to this error. I am unable to trace it that from where it is produced.

```
app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x012dcbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014315c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x012d26e5 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 261
    3   Dispatch                            0x0002feeb -[ZoneFareTaxi parseMessage:] + 754
    4   Dispatch                            0x0002fbf0 -[ZoneFareTaxi initWithMessageString:] + 92
    5   Dispatch                            0x0003b949 -[ServerConnection onUdpSocket:didReceiveData:withTag:fromHost:port:] + 8862
    6   Dispatch                            0x0002350e -[AsyncUdpSocket maybeCompleteCurrentReceive] + 458
    7   Dispatch                            0x00023210 -[AsyncUdpSocket doReceive:] + 1364
    8   Dispatch                            0x00022c60 -[AsyncUdpSocket doReceive4] + 80
    9   Dispatch                            0x00022add -[AsyncUdpSocket maybeDequeueReceive] + 561
    10  Foundation                          0x000da7f6 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x012bdfe3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x012bf594 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0121bcc9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0121b240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0121b161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    16  GraphicsServices                    0x01a4d268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x01a4d32d GSEventRun + 115
    18  UIKit                               0x0036a42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    19  Dispatch                            0x000024b4 main + 102
    20  Dispatch                            0x00002445 start + 53
    21  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: before accessing your array, print [yourArray count];

Comment: You have an array somewhere that is getting out of bounds. IE, you defined an array with 4 elements, but it is trying to access a 5th element (or an index with a negative number). If you show us the code, I can try to find it for you.

Comment: error says your trying to access invalid index of array..

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: @filipe error message is pretty clear but I am unable to find it from thousands of line of code ... my purpose  of posting it here was to get idea that where to hit to catch the exception generating code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely an off by one error. Your `NSMutableArray` has only 5 elements and you are accessing the 6th object at index 5. Indexes are 0 based.

The problem resides likely in this method: `[ZoneFareTaxi parseMessage:]`

Comment: thanks Daniel and can you please tell me that how did you read this stack trace so that in future I could do this with my own .... ?

Comment: I just walked down from the top and the it was the first thing that could be your code.

Comment: Thanks Daniel .. I got the problem .. thats it

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the `parseMessage` method implementation, of the class `ZoneFareTaxi`.
In that method you send the message `objectAtIndex:` to an `NSMutableArray` object, passing a value that in that case is 5 (presumably using a variable).

It says that you are accessing to the sixth element of the array, while it has only 5 elements. Arrays are 0 indexed.

Answer (score 0):

this problem only appears only if your trying to  access an element from array with index is greater than your count of array.

Answer (score 0):

From this:

```
-[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]
```

you can see that you're trying to access index 5 in an array that only goes from 0 to 4.

From this:

```
objc_exception_throw + 47
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 261
-[ZoneFareTaxi parseMessage:] + 754
```

you can see that the problem is happening in your `[ZoneFareTaxi parseMessage:]` method.